# How to use a greped url provided by tshark inside a bash script?

Tags: grep, ffmpeg, url, tshark

I'm trying to use a url piped from tshark into a while loop.

```
while read line ; do 
echo "$line"
ffmpeg -i "$line" -c copy "filename"
done < <(tshark -i tun0 -B 50 -P -V -q -l -Y 'http matches "(?<=\[Full request URI: )(http://mywebsite.com/file.*)(?=\])"' 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -Po "(?<=\[Full request URI: )(http://mywebsite.com/file.*)(?=\])" | unbuffer -p uniq)
```

Inside the loop, I'm able to echo $line just fine; and it looks like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/file?eid=5345944&fmt=5&app_id=214748364&range=20-30&etsp=1456777145&hmac=1K9nwkA8TOgtOXAsakSfMMVWsuE
```

But for some reason, I'm unable to use this same "line" variable to feed ffmpeg, inside the same while loop. Doing

```
ffmpeg -i "$line" -c copy "filename"
```

results in (all quotes are accurately copy pasted)

```
[http @ 0x1ab5ec0] HTTP error 400 Bad Request:
Server returned 400 Bad Request5345932&fmt=5&app_id=214748364&range=20-30&etsp=1456779359&hmac=35B2lA6D0zfR2DmfdPS4ZcilYxg
```

On the other hand, copying the url (from the echo output), double quoting it and using the same ffmpeg command in a terminal works perfectly.

Also, for some reason, the command is truncated when running the script with -xv, in such way that it does not show the full "+ ffmpeg -i 'http://...." line as it should.

Comment: You want to make sure you escape the ampersands, but your code is a pain to read all on one line as it is, so I am not going to try.  It will involve nested quoting most likely, or some well placed backslashes.  Please edit your doe to be more readable.

Comment: Sorry about the bad readability, just edited. Do you mean I should run the variable value through sed to escape each ampersand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
It appears the grep is capturing a newline or carriage return which is fine when you submit it as a one off command but not fine in the loop.  Add tr -d '\r'

Comment: That is exactly what OP complains doesn't work...

Comment: @vonbrand, he edited his code after I submitted that, it didn't look like that at the time.

Comment: Let's see the full output please.

Comment: Update the question with this info, don't use a comment, its impossible to read.  Are you are using the same URL for the -c copy argument?  If so, you need to quote properly there as well, this URL contains some special characters which will affect the shell.

Comment: What are all those extra single quotes and backslashes?  Are you sure your grep command is extracting a single url with no additional cruft?  Did you try removing the line buffering stuff?

Comment: If your copy file name has ampersands it need to be in single quotes too.

Comment: I don't understand it either. I don't even get to see the full `ffmpeg -i mywebsite.com -c copy filename` command, it just starts with `'mywebsite.com ...`  Also, no ampersand in filename, and if I take buffering awway, the script hangs (as it waits for input).

Comment: Also, the grep command works just fine (echo shows me only the bare url).

Comment: add an echo before the ffmpeg and show the output of that line.

Comment: EDIT 2 shows the output of `echo "$line"`

Comment: It is weird that the single quote after the URL in that echo shows on the next line, perhaps you are capturing a newline in your grep?  Try changing "'$line'" to "'$(echo $line|tr -d '\n')'"

Comment: Sorry for replying late. You were 99% right ! For some reason, I'm  getting a carriage return into the $line variable. So what finally worked for me was to replace it with $(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r'). If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction !

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that grep (or tshark ?) is capturing a carriage return into the `$line` variable, as pointed out by Gregg Leventhal. This carriage return needs to be stripped off.

Replacing `$line` inside the loop with`$(echo "$line" | tr -d '\r')` did the trick for me!